# How to use TCP over serial (custom PHY) in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, tcp

I have several devices with RF module working on 433mhz.
When device transmit one byte it appers on other devices. 
So I have shared communication environment.

In order to make those devices communicate efficiently with each other I want to implement TCP over this environment.
Has anyone tried something like that in .NET?

[image]
(http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/raswik-radio.png)

Closest things I've found:

- managed TCP/IP stack for .NET MicroFramework  https://mip.codeplex.com
- nice blog post on how to use uIP + SLIP https://harizanov.com/2013/03/tcpip-over-rfm12b-and-raspberry-pi-as-gateway/

Comment: Dont even attempt it, tcp is a complicated protocol which sounds like overkill ... Have a look at simple protocols which achieve the behaviours you're after. Otherwise good luck ....

Comment: The general idea to build reliable communication over unreliable transmition environment. Since TCP is already implemented and working, the first thought is to use TCP instead of inventing new protocol with adressing and error correction. @FloatingKiwi could you by chance point to any simple protocol?

Comment: Sorry, not my area of expertise. You might try asking for a recommendation on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or one of the other websites. You may wish to check out PGM (pragmatic general multicast) for an approach.

Comment: How your devices connected to PC? Through serial port? May be, in this case simplest way to solve your problem - to use the software modem emulator, that, nevertheless  connected to real com-port. Existent software modem emulator implementations really sends the data through the ethernet adapters or another "traditionally" network device. You need to find open-source software modem emulator implementation and modify it to use physical com-port or other, which you are going use.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev they are not. They communicate only with each other. Device is a Raspberry pi with attached RF module (see picture) so apps can send and recieve bytes. Not sure if there are any modem emulators for NET.